# How do I insert grid view value into SQL Server database in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am creating a time in time out program in which when you click at a row in grid view it gets the data of the employee's last name, first name and middle name, then when I click the button, that data will be inserted to an inner joined table which is the time in time out table where the employee is set as `Lname + Fname + Mname AS Employee_name`

Here is my code - I need help with inserting the grid view data

```
SqlConnection con = new 
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ConnectionString);


        string command = "INSERT INTO DTR(EmpRegID, CheckIn) VALUES (@EmpRegID, @CheckIn)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CheckIn", DateTime.Now.ToString());

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            GridView2.DataBind();
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: You need parameter for `EmpRegID`, and then execute query - `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It looks like you aren't actually submitting the updated data. Youll most likely need a NonQuery for that.

Comment: @Win good sir what should i put in the parameters of EmpRegID

Comment: btw. `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CheckIn", DateTime.Now.ToString());` .... is Your `CheckIn` field in database `nvarchar` or `nchar` datatype? ... other, if Your `EmpRegID` is `autoincrement` then You don't need it command string.

Comment: @nelek my check in field's datatype is datetime

Comment: If it is `datetime` why You conver it to string? I think correct way should be `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CheckIn", DateTime.Now);` without `ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

finally i have done it thank you guys for your answers so here is the code

```
        string test1 = test.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ConnectionString);
        string command = "INSERT INTO DTR(RegEmpID, CheckIn) VALUES (@RegEmpID, @CheckIn)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegEmpID", test1);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CheckIn", DateTime.Now.ToString());

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            GridView2.DataBind();
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
```